# Can anyone help me to understand this $\mathscr{N}\left(x^t \left| µ^t , \sigma^t \right. \right)$?

Tags: normal-distribution

I'm reading a paper "Recurrent Autoregressive Networks for Online Multi-Object Tracking"

The equation (2) in the paper, there is $\mathscr{N}\left( x^t \left| \mu^t , \sigma^t \right. \right)$ which i don't understand

[image]

Seems that is normal distribution, but what is $\left| \right.$ meaning for $\mathscr{N}\left(\right)$?

$\mathscr{N}\left(\right)$ requires $\mu^t$ as mean value ($N$ size vector), $\sigma^t$ as variance matrix, regarding this paper. So, $\mathscr{N}\left(\right)$ is pdf? and $x^t$ is input vectors for $\mathscr{N}\left(\right)$?

Comment: (2) has problem on math writing. How can a probability  (suppose Pr means probability) equal to a distribution?

Comment: @user158565: this is sloppy notation of applied statistics people: usually it is the „magic“ p symbol that sometimes means probability and sometimes density. They don’t really seem to notice any difference here. It stems from the misinterpretation of the fact that a discrete random variable has density $f_X(x)=P[X=x]$ w.r.t. the counting measure... weird but seems to be „accepted“ to write it in that way...

Answer (score 1):

The superscripts are referring to the time steps so $t$ refers to the "current" time and $1:t-1$ refers to the previous times, etc.  The first of your highlighted parts is simply giving you the distribution of $\mathbf{x}^t$ conditional on $\mathbf{x}^{1:t-1}$, which is normal with mean $\mu^t$ and variance $\Sigma^t$, both of which are given in the subsequent equations.

As to the meaning of the rest of the notation, it is a bit loose, but presumably $\mathcal{N}$ is referring to the normal density and the use of $\text{Pr}$ is not strictly correct (since it is referring to a density function, not a probability).  The separator $|$ is standard notation to separate the argument of the density function from its parameters.